# Easy bound on number of points on a variety over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, finite-fields

Let $V$ be a closed algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^n$ defined over a finite field $K$, with irreducible components $Z_1,\dotsc,Z_m$. Let $D = \sum_i \deg Z_i$ and $d = \max_i \dim Z_i$.

Then $$|V(K)|\leq D |K|^d.$$

Where is the first place where this general bound appears? Or, at least as useful: what is a classical, standard reference for this bound?

What I know:

- The special case of $V$ a hypersurface was apparently proved by Ore in 1922 (Wikipedia says). Schwarz/Zippel/DeMillon-Lipton (1978--1980) is a generalization to counting points with coordinates in a set $S\subset K$.
- This is "morally weaker" (but not strictly speaking weaker) than Lang-Weil (1954).
- For $V$ defined over $\overline{K}$, the bound $|V(\overline{K})\cap \mathbb{A}^n(K)|\leq D |K|^d$ is still true; that was proved in Lachaud-Rolland (2015) (a rather recent source!).

Comment: I do think that Lang-Weil is the original place where this first appeared. Of course this paper is more well known for Theorem 1, which gives an asymptotic formula for the number of points. But to prove this they needed this upper bound, which they prove in Lemma 1 (albeit with a different leading constant, but I suspect their proof also gives this constant for affine varieties).